# In Dynamic 365 - Customer Engagement , where to find the Field description?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have been provided with Dynamics 365 access to Customer Engagement . I also have Sandbox access.

Could you please help me for my below questions

1. How can I find - which database is the backend for my dyanamics 365
2. Where can I find the list of all database tables that is being queried by dynamics 365
3. Where can I find the list of all tables, which are created by Dynamics 365 , but does not exists in Database backend
4. How to get the description of each of the column in each of the tables. To understand the business requirement of such column.

Thanks,
Sabarisri

Comment: backend is Azure SQL Server, for the other questions, Metadata Browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for online Dynamics 365, you can use SSMS, and connect to the azure db using ur organization-id as server name `{organizationid}.crm4.dynamics.com,5558`
[image]

this will give you read only access to the database so you can query what you need check [how to access crm database](https://dynamics-chronicles.com/article/how-access-dynamics-365-online-sql-server-database) ,
as for the details about the columns as [Guido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2191473/guido-preite)  mentioned you can import [Metadata Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/browse-your-metadata?view=op-9-1) to your environment and check all the columns details